# function to detect cli installation

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, zsh

I have inline checking to detect the installation of cli packages to save time on installing existing package, but I found it is tedious and not that readable for those long list.

For example:

```
which -s redis-cli || brew install redis
which -s java || brew cask install java
which -s yarn || npm install -g yarn
```

Are there any function to make it nice looking? For example:

```
function npmInstall(name) {
    if (which -s name) {
      return;
    }

    npm install -g name;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass client packages as parameters.

Example, **script.sh**:

```
for cli in $@; do
  which "$cli" || npm install -g "$cli"
done
```

invoked with `./script.sh java yarn`

**Update:**

As package names may differs from executable names, you can handle these differences using a Bash associative array. Package name passed as parameter  to the script will be used only if no value is found in the array for that package:

```
for pkg in $@; do
  declare -A exe
  exe=([redis]="redis-cli" [otherpkg]="otherpkg-cli")
  package=${exe[$pkg]:-$pkg} 
  which "$package" || npm install -g "$package"
done
```